# Is there any suggestion to turnoff or escape JMS translation header 'type' to JMSType?

Tags: python, jms, activemq-classic, stomp

Messages sending by Stomp through ActiveMQ to JMS.

Is there any suggestion to turnoff or escape JMS translation header '**type**' to **JMSType** ? 
I need to use exactly '**type**' from header as property of **ByteMessage**. (can't add code to JMS server)

*For using AMQP I have to use 1.0 version clients on Python, so it is only python-qpid-proton. But it can't works with Protobuf. I've got wrong bytes on JMS server.*

Comment: Need more info here on what you are doing, code samples, errors etc.  Don't make people try and guess what you are doing

Comment: @TimBish No errors, no code for understanding the problem... JMS translate 'type' header to JMStype property for ByteMessage and I asked how to escape it.